# What happened to SIGUSR in Python?

Tags: python, signals

On a linux system (tried two debian based ones) I would like to send user signals to a python application.

I find that the following code (adopted from a different stack exchange question) works as expected with python 2.7, but throws an error with python 3.5

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import signal
import os
import time

def receive_signal(signum, stack):
    print('Received:', signum)

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, receive_signal)
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2, receive_signal)

print('My PID is:', os.getpid())

while True:
    print('Waiting...')
    time.sleep(3)
```

In latter case the error I get reads

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/signal.py", line 3, in <module>
import signal
  File "[...]/signal.py", line 10, in <module>
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, receive_signal)
AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGUSR1
```

I cannot seem to find information about it. Has the name been deprecated?

Comment: Did you test both Python versions on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, but I am guessing that the linked answer applies. Wasn't aware that there has been a change.

Comment: While the referenced question is not a duplicate of mine its answer indeed answers mine.